# Transparent warp class in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to create a transparent wrap: a class which passes all references (apart from some few) to one of its fields. I have got this:

```
class Wrap():

  def __init__(self,val,parent):
    self.__dict__['val']=val
    self.__dict__['parent']=parent

  def SetValue(self,val):
    self.__dict__['val']=val

  def __getattr__(self,attr):
    return  self.__dict__['val'].__getattribute__(attr)

  def __setattr__(self,attr,val):
    self.__dict__['val'].__setattribute__(attr,val)
```

The problem is that the wrap doesn't seems to pass `__getitem__/__setitem__` calls and I get `TypeError: 'Wrap' object does not support item assignment` when I try subscript the `wrap`, although `val` is subscriptable. Is it any workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately "magic" methods cannot be simply proxied.  See the duplicate question for a way to make it work.  I consider this one of the biggest outstanding warts in Python.

Comment: Thank you very much. Should i delete my question?

Comment: No need to delete it, you can leave it as a signpost to the duplicate.